# Using the Clip Studio Paint Lasso fill tool to fill an preexisting closed shape?

Tags: fill, clip-studio-paint

I have seen videos in which CSP’s lasso fill tool is used, not to fill the shape being drawn, but in order to fill an existing (closed) shape.

Here is an example : https://youtu.be/YgVWO8qieYs

- Timestamp 4:26-4:30 -

For that specific purpose, drawing a contour enclosing the shape to be filled will result in the targeted shape to be filled rather than in the  currently (enclosing) contour to be filled.

Since this does not seem to be the primary aim of the lasso fill tool, I guess, it requires some settings to be modified (at the tools level or at the layers level or both).

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you tell us the time stamp where the tool is used in the video? Nobody here is going to watch a 17 minute tutorial to find it. Also if you are stuck on a tutorial, might be better to leave a comment on the video asking for clarity. It's often really hard to unpick someone else's tutorial.

Comment: @BillyKerr : Thanks. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I've never used this software before but it looks like it's based on layers and having no gaps (or a setting to close gaps) in your illustration.  Also looks like it may not be the normal lasso tool, the title of the video says "Lasso fill tool" - but the tool option in the video is written in chinese or japanese characters and I can't read what it says. Sorry.

Comment: It is in fact a Japanese piece of software, formerly known as Manga Studio, which claims (rightfully so, I believe) to be more efficient for manga or cartoon creation than Photoshop or Paintshop.

Comment: Then you might be better reaching out to the creator of the video.  It's more a kind of specialist software, rather than a typical graphic design tool

Comment: All right, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

i have this enabled on my up to date clip studio.
but i know you have to have your lineart on one layer. and right next to the clipping layer button, theres "set as reference layer."
then, with your bucket tool, select the "enclose and fill" setting.you might need to fiddle with its settings in the brush setting tab to fit your lineart. i dont know exactly how it works lol, i just pressed buttons and slid things around, but i havent had to change mine much since i set it.

though i should add, the video looks like a downloadable brush type thing. haha. this is just how i do it, and its the same thing.